# how to divide bootstrap 4 cards

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

using Bootstrap 4 to My Application and I am using following card system as well.

```
 
   <div class="card-body text-success">
   
   </div>
```

I need divide above card to same height and width 3 columns and two rows. Then how could I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not so difficult.
I tried like this.

```
<div class="card-body text-success">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Your text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```